# How to structure routing in an Angular js and Lithium app?

Tags: angularjs, lithium

So I am planning out an app of moderate complexity using Angular for the frontend and Lithium for the backend. I'm full of questions at this point, but for this post I would like some ideas on templating. Both lithium and Angular have the capacity to handle the entire view layer, but I'd rather treat it like a single page app, so Angular will handle this.

Now how would I handle routes? Would Lithium basically be dumb of the current routes beyond the index? Should API endpoints have a special url scheme separate from the view URLs?

This is how I am thinking now::

theapp.com/dashboard/calendar/event/eventID :: for a view handled by Angular
&
theapp.com/api/event/eventID :: for an API endpoint

I'm quite new to building something this complex so please forgive me if this is a simple question. :)

Am I totally off the mark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This presentation should be helpful: http://li3-angular.lithium-framework.com/

What you're planning is the way to go: Li3 expose a json api, and Angular handles your routes and views. Your URL scheme should follow REST principles.

- li3_resources will help you to build a RESTful api: https://github.com/nateabele/li3_resources
- Angular UI router should help you with your routes: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Great thanks! We'll look into this route. :) Good to know I have the right general idea about how a REST app should be structured. Not too bad for a designer :D.

Comment: The presentation is no longer available at that URL but you can clone it here: https://github.com/nateabele/li3-angular-presentation